# Group by and merge by column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an entity Report

```
Report(id: integer, pos: integer, project_id: integer, key_id: integer, created_at: datetime)
```

Because there are records with same values, but only the `pos` different I would like to group them by `key_id` and `merge` the `pos` column.

One way of doing:

```
Report.group(:key_id, :pos).select(:key_id, :pos) OR .size
```

And loop throw each one, and if there is a match on key_id append the new `pos`

Expected output:

```
 1. {"key" => "key_id", "pos" => "pos"}
 2. {"key" => "key_id", "pos" => "pos1"}
 Result => {"key" => "key_id", "pos" => "pos, pos1"}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
[{"key" => "key_id", "pos" => "pos"}, {"key" => "key_id", "pos" => "pos1"}].group_by { |hash| hash[:id] }.map do |id, hashes|
  hashes.reduce do |a, b|
    a.merge(b) { |key, v1, v2| v1 == v2 ? v1 : [v1, v2].flatten }
  end
end
```

enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It may work for you.

```
Report.select("key_id,pos").group("key_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be costly but i think so in your case this is the right solution.

```
result = {}
Report.group(:key_id).count.keys.each do |report|
    result[report] = Report.where(:key_id => report).map(&:pos).join(", ")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what database you're using, but in PostgreSQL you can do;

```
Report.select(:key_id, 'array_agg(pos)').group(:key_id).pluck(:key_id, 'array_agg(pos)')
```

or similar.

mysql has group_concat and I'd imagine usage would be similar.